# Is this on topic (IF not, on what grounds)?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

> I read last year that xlrd was being updated to be able to read xlsx files (Excel 2007, 2010). Is there any news on this development, or the use of other Python utilities?

An actual, complete question (from a while ago) but I have not provided a link for fear of the meta effect and because it seems unnecessary to do so. In part because the specific example does not matter since what I would like clarified is where the boundary lies for on/off topic, with particular reference to questions of ephemeral relevance and of the type of the example.

Comment: Sounds off-topic for not being about programming. About a programming *library* perhaps, but not a real programming question.

Comment: "any news on this development" -- likely off-topic as we just can't answer: ask the devs, look at the public repo (if any), etc.  "the use of other Python utilities" -- if phrased as "How do I consume xlsx files in Python?", maybe on-topic, maybe too broad (better if you can say _what_ you want to do with those xlsx files); if phrased as "Give me a Python library to consume xlsx files", off-topic: recommendation.

Comment: Most questions like this, especially those that have been heavily upvoted were asked in 2009 and 2010 when such questions were much more welcome.  They should still be judged based on today's standards, so if you feel it is off-topic, vote to close.

Comment: Asking when the next update to .NET will be isn't really about programming either as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @pnuts it;s not about programming - it is asking about the development cycle of a specific tool.  Pre Jul 2013, I would have voted to close as too localized.  Today, I would have selected the most applicable off-topic reason or left a custom reason (that is why we have custom reasons).  In this case, I selected "off-topic / questions about software...."

Comment: The question was put off-topic 8 hours ago, regardless of whether you provided the link or not the Meta effect will always happen.

Answer (score 7):

It's an ancient question from a time of different standards. Now it's an obsolete ancient question.